# Autocomplete JSX html tags in VS2019

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2017, jsx

Two IMPORTANT clarifications first:
1. I'm looking for advice about VS2017/19, NOT VSCode.
2. I've looked through other threads about this. Link them if you so desire, but please explain what you want me to see in those threads.

Problem:
When I write html in a .tsx file, it does not autocomplete the html tags. (It does recognize the html tags, however - no problem there).

Attempted solutions:
1. In tools > options > text editor, I looked for settings pertaining to JSX. Under HTML I see the setting for autocompleting tags. However I do not see anything for JSX. I see typescript, but there are no settings there about jsx.
2. I've looked into creating my own legacy language service. This looks like it may work but is sort of reinventing the wheel. I can't believe it would be so hard to get autocompletion in JSX.
3. There may also be some extension I can write? I'm not familiar with writing vs extensions.

On learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/javascript-in-vs-2017?view=vs-2019#/JSX they say "JavaScript in Visual Studio 2017 has rich support for the JSX syntax that allows HTML tags within JavaScript files." It really seems to imply that what I'm looking for exists... somewhere.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.